# Several queries related to JRXML / Jasper Reports -- fixing cell size in excel, using passed parameters in jrxml

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am setting two dates as string in the map as below:

```
Map<String, String> hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
hashmap.put("date1", date1);
hashmap.put("date2", date2);
```

This i am using as below:

```
JasperReport jasperReport1 = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(this.reportName1);
JasperPrint jasperPrint1 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport1, hashmap, con);
jprintList.add(jasperPrint1);
```

1) How to use this passed parameters in the JRXML file.

Basically I am comparing two columns on date i.e. Col 1 for date1 alongside Col 2 for date2.

So, I want to use these date values in column headers.

```
<columnHeader>
    <band height="11">
    <rectangle>
      <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="920" height="11" backcolor="#333333"/>
      <graphicElement/>
    </rectangle>
    <staticText>
     <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="20" y="0" width="80" height="11" forecolor="#ffffff" backcolor="#333333" style="Arial_Bold"/>
      <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
        <text><![CDATA[Column for <here should come date1>]]></text>
     </staticText>
      <staticText>
     <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="20" y="0" width="80" height="11" forecolor="#ffffff" backcolor="#333333" style="Arial_Bold"/>
      <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
        <text><![CDATA[Column for <here should come date2>]]></text>
     </staticText>
  </columnHeader>
```

The date values are to be used in the place " in above code.

2) How to wrap the text forming column title ?

I am exporting the report in excel.

To keep the column title informative, I have the title as "column showing prices for date 12/12/2011" -- which is pretty long as I have total 13 columns each having such long title.

How to wrap the text or how to fix the cell size of column title in excel.

What changes should I do in my JRXML ?

3) I am passing several reports in a jprintlist. Each report is getting published in separate worksheets in the final excel file. How to give names to worksheets ? By default it takes jasperReport's name attribute from  tag and adds 1, 2 to the end.

Ans: Got the answer to this

```
exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.SHEET_NAMES, new String[]{”Personal Information”, “Skills”});
```

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) How to use this passed parameters in the JRXML file.

You can use *`$P{}`* expression for using parameters. The sample:

```xml
<text><![CDATA[Column for $P{date}]]></text>
```

> 2) How to wrap the text forming column title?

You can use the ***isStretchWithOverflow*** and ***stretchType*** to allow the title growing.

The sample:

```xml
<columnHeader>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <box leftPadding="5">
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Column for " + $P{title1}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <box leftPadding="5">
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Column for " + $P{title2}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
```

The result will be (Excel preview):

[image]

You can also try to set ***net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.wrap.text*** property for *textField* element. You can read about this property [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.wrap.text).

The sample:

```xml
<textField>
    <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.wrap.text" value="false"/>
    </reportElement>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Column for " + $P{title2}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! For the first query, to make the answer complete, we need to declare parameter in our JRXML at the top like: <parameter name="date1" class="java.lang.String"/>